# Change CreateFileW dwShareMode

Tags: file, winapi, file-locking

Is there a way to use CreateFileW and with FILE_SHARE_WRITE and then after a while change that to only FILE_SHARE_READ?

I could not find any documentation, but it seems memory map files can elevate permissions, so I guess maybe there is a way for opening a file, just to read, and then lock it for write.

Comment: no, this is impossible. also memory map files can **not** elevate permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions and sharing conflicts are checked when a file is opened.  So if you want to have a more restrictive sharing more (change from `FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ` to only `FILE_SHARE_READ`) you need to go through that process again.

Be prepared for your `CreateFile` to fail since there can be a handle open with write access.

Locking can be done without reopening the file, but those locks are cooperative/voluntary (and lock operations can also fail).

Comment: How do you lock without reopening?

Comment: @Okoba: `LockFileEx` function works on an already-opened file (you pass the file handle, not the pathname).   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/locking-and-unlocking-byte-ranges-in-files